# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, environment-variables

I've changed .env file where I wrote the new name of my DB but still it returns the error where the old name is mentioned.

```
("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=X-db", "X-user", "", [])
```

How can I save the changes I've made and why does not the server save them automatically?
Thank You All !!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqvO3.png)

Comment: Adding imperatives like "urgent" and "hurry" [should not be added to questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/) as they will reduce the likelihood that you will receive answers to your question as it is just noise at best, and considered rude at worst.

Comment: OK. I've already edited my post :)

Comment: Did you try clearing your config cache? I think the command is `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Yes,I run that command. Nothing is changed still.

Comment: I also added the error screenshot. Can you understand where is the real problem?

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer. I've already changed it and it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `host=db` is wrong. You can change it like `host=localhost` or you need to add a line like `127.0.0.1 db` in your hosts file.

Comment: I've already changed it and it worked ! 
Thank You very much for your answer !